# Docky can't open apps which are added by "pin to dock"

Tags: xubuntu, docky

I just installed Docky on Xubuntu and for adding Home folder and Terminal to it, i opened these apps and clicked on their icons for "Pin to dock". Now, when i close them and then click on their respective icons on Docky, nothing happens. What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with some java application. You can try to drop some applications' shortcut from `/usr/share/applications` to your dock. (If some applications are not in this folder you just need to create a new `.desktop` file).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create shortcuts of your apps
2. Put them into folder `/usr/share/applications`
3. Finally put them into docky.

Tested on Debian 7 Xfce.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to correct this issue (on 12.04) with Terminal and Thunar by editing the Menu:

Right-click **Menu**, select **Properties**, then **Edit Menu**, select **Accessories** category on the left, and then, on the right, untick **File manager** and tick **Thunar File Manager** instead. For terminal, untick **Terminal Emulator** and tick **Terminal**.

Then, open **Start Menu** and drag the application icon directly onto Docky. From now on the launchers in Docky should work and the icons should display correctly

Answer (score 0):

Docky basically displays the programs/folders/whatever you have on your desktop.

If you put something into Docky and deleted it on the desktop, it will not work.

If you did this, simply put the programs out of the trashbin on your desktop.